Failed Unit Tests Troubleshooting
What is proper way to troubleshoot failed Unit Test (or End2End Test) when very complex logic is under the test ? It is common advise in to inject NullLogger to the tested class for unit testing.
Assume that CI/CD pipeline fails during Unit test phase and the only outcome from ITestOutputHelper is which test failed and where (which Assert failed). For example:
EvtHandlerAsyncInvokeIsProcessed
   Source: AsyncTests.cs line 29
   Duration: 213 ms

Message: 
Assert.That(eventData).IsEqualTo("my value", StringComparison.Ordinal)
Expected: "my value"
Received: "myexample string"


Difference at index 2:
   myexample string
     ^
   my value
     ^

  Stack Trace: 
InvokableAssertionBuilder`1.ProcessAssertionsAsync()
AsyncTests.EvtHandlerAsyncInvokeIsProcessed() line 46

If program is normally started, it is usually configured to log to console/file to enable figure out what happened before program crashed, but from Unit tests, there are no logs available giving hints what steps led to the failure.
It would be helpful to read full logs from failed unit test and be able to figure out (without running the unit test again in Debug mode in IDE or recreate the same scenario in non-unit test setup to get to the logs).
How is this done in effective way ?
Do you run failed unit test again within Unit test automatically with injected "file/console logger" to log more details about the failed scenario ? I assume that might not be trivial as more tests are running in parallel and it would be helpful to log each unit test to separate file would be helpful.
Or does the injected logger log directly into ITestOutputHelper ?

Why couldn't you run unit tests on your local machine and debug?

You've answered the question yourself when you wrote "I assume that might not be trivial" and you are right. Trying to find a unit test failure from logs is never going to be easy - the logs are unlikely to ever cover enough for you to pinpoint the cause of the failure, whereas in a debugger you'll get straight to the issue.

@iakobski I have very detailed logging to be able (with TRACE level on ) in production (for limited time) to figure out exactly, why application failed just based on logs. So I produce enough logs.

@MichałTurczyn Even if I run Unit test in debug mode, I am missing logs. It is much easier to read full logs without the need to go step by step manually to to figure out what happened. Afre reading logs I can go set up break point to the "suspected method" and to verify the root cause.

Why not always write your log output to ITestOutputHelper?

@walter33 you ask "what is the proper way?" and the answer is to run the test in a debugger. Logs are for diagnosing problems when the actual system is running, either in production or a test environment. Unit tests serve two main purposes: to verify that changes haven't broken code, and to allow you to run specific parts of the code easily in a development environment. Unless your very detailed logging logs every line of code, including the values of all variables and the call stack, it's much easier to do in a debugger. And that's before unpicking which test wrote each log line!

Very rarely, you might have to diagnose a case where a unit test fails on a build server but not locally. This can involve turning on logging/trace and probably creating a special build that runs just that test. But this is an edge case.

I have am exploring logger helpers utilizing ITestOutputHelper  . One example including nuget is here https://www.meziantou.net/how-to-get-asp-net-core-logs-in-the-output-of-xunit-tests.htm. I am still in progress migrating Unit tests to https://github.com/thomhurst/TUnit using new Microsoft.Testing.Platform.
